# Working at Amazon and receiving Restricted Stock Units as compensation Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, finance, investment

Amazon includes RSUs as a part of the total employee compensation. However, the company stock is non-sharia compliant http://testblog.islamicly.com/StockReport/shariah-stock-status-report-amazon-inc-usa-nasdaq/

My question is, as a software developer that is not directly working in any of the non-sharia compliant team, is it ok for me to receive the RSUs as a part of compensation?

What if, for example, my compensation includes $10,000 worth of stock with a vesting period, and when the vesting period is done, I immediately sell the stock and keep the $10,000, and if there's any bonus amount that's earned, I can give it to charity.

Amazon gives a larger part of compensation as stock for more senior roles, so an employee is really dependent on that as well..

Also, I found this on a forum https://forum.islamicfinanceguru.com/t/working-at-amazon/294/3